# Query to convert for DATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello I have a question that transpose column type to DATE.

My Origint Data that for transpose to DATE is below. And **there type is VARCHAR, structure is MM/DD/YY**

how can i transpose to DATE type??

```
01-05-75
06-04-66
07-05-66
...
```

Comment: Are all dates from 1900s? Are you using a scripting language or just mysql?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(CONCAT(
    '19', SUBSTRING(col, 7, 2), /* year, assuming all years are between 1900 and 1999) */
    '-',
    SUBSTRING(col, 1, 2), /* month */
    '-',
    SUBSTRING(col, 4, 2) /* day */
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

```
SELECT 
    STR_TO_DATE(
        CONCAT(LEFT(`date`,6), '19', RIGHT(`date`, 2)), 
        '%m-%d-%Y'
    ) 
FROM 
    tab
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qf9sudzTdjXZ9Gd8qsJh42/0).

Comment: (Note this answer also presumes all years are from 1900s. If not the task is not achievable, or a metric needs to be defined for other centuries)

Comment: Yes, 100% agree. I'm supposing the retrieved data for this specific problem does not belong to the future (given that we currently live in 2022).